# Creating a variable with function parameters

Tags: javascript, function

How can I create a variable that stores function parameters that can be called multiple times instead of having to repeat the same parameters when I want to invoke it? (The following example isn't really a case where you would *want* to store function parameters, but in cases where you have multiple parameters of varying lengths that may get used in multiple places, it would be very handy).

```
function showAlerts(alert1,alert2) {
    console.log(alert1 + '\n' + alert2);
}

// I would like to be able to define a variable that can be called later
// doing it this way (obviously) just runs the function immediately
var alerts1 = showAlerts('test1','test2');
var alerts2 = [showAlerts('test3','test4')];
var alerts3 = ['test5','test6'];

if(0===1) {
  alerts1; 
} else if(1===0) {
  alerts2;
} else {
  showAlerts(alerts3);
}
```

http://jsbin.com/cenili/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: You should do some reading on [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), and [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). `bind` is useful in this case and you'll find the other two of use elsewhere.

Comment: What you're asking about is called [partial application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). I expect there's probably an existing javascript question that answers this, but I haven't found it and I'm not comfortable enough with javascript to give you a good answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.bind()`:

```
var alerts1 = showAlerts.bind(undefined, "test1", "test2");

alerts1(); // note the () which are still necessary to call the function
```

The first parameter to `.bind()` is the value to be bound to `this` when the function is called, and that's what most people do with `.bind()`. However any additional arguments are passed along as parameters.

You can still pass parameters with `alerts1()`, and they'd be the third, fourth, fifth, etc. parameters.

Comment: Note that once you bind, you can't re-bind different parameters.

Answer (score -2):

use closures, the internal function getting returned will have parameters bound to it. Plus it's  cross browser, will work in older browsers not supporting `bind`

```
function getShowAlertsFunc() {
    var args = arguments
    return function() {
        for(var i=0; i<args.length; i++) {
            console.log(args[i]);   
        }
    }
}
```

usage

```
var alert1 = getShowAlertsFunc("john", "doe")
var alert2 = getShowAlertsFunc("jane", "doe")
var alert3 = getShowAlertsFunc("test", "abc", "123")

alert1()
alert2()
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This answer is about calling a function with a variable number of parameters and not `How can I create a variable that stores function parameters...`

Comment: The OP is looking for a way to create a function that already has the arguments embedded on it. Your answer does not solve that problem.

Comment: Consider renaming your function. This function returns a function which 'shows alerts', it does not actually run the function it creates.